# How can I get the Syntactic Tree from a SemanticGraph?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have a `SemanticGraph` object and I want to get the syntactic tree (`Tree` Object) from that `SemanticGraph`. I know that the `SemanticGraph` is(can) be generated from a `Tree`, what I ask for is the inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is supported at this time.  The easiest thing to do is use an Annotation object which will store the SemanticGraph and Tree object for a given sentence together.

Comment: But it will not generate the tree, true ?

Comment: I do not think we have any functionality that will generate a tree from a semantic graph.

Comment: Can you clarify where the SemanticGraph objects are coming from?  It seems better to either build an Annotation (http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html) or keep the Tree instead.

Comment: I have some files outputted from CoreNLP in .conll (conll-x format), and I want to deserialize them into an Annotation object. I used the method `TreebankLangParserParams.readGrammaticalStructureFromFile(conllXFileName)` to deserlize the depTree into a `GrammaticalStructure`, then into `SemanticGraph` object

Comment: I have all the annotation that i need except the syntactic tree (the Tree Object)

Comment: When you serialize your Annotations in conll-x, can you also serialize them with the ProtobufAnnotationSerializer?  This way you can store the entire Annotation on disk...we recommend serializing with ProtobufAnnotationSerializer

Comment: I can but unfortunately I already parse a large collection in conll-x format, and know i try to see if their a way to generate the Tree, otherwise I have to parse all trees again

Comment: I asked around to confirm...unfortunately you're going to have to parse the trees again.  We do not have any functionality for mapping dependency parses to constituency parses.  You'd have to implement this paper: http://repository.cmu.edu/lti/162/